# error: (-215:Assertion failed) sources.size() == modalities.size() in function 'cv::linemod::Detector::match'

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

template = cv2.imread('./light_t.jpg')
template = cv2.resize(template, (200, 200))
print(template.shape)
lineModDetector = cv2.linemod.getDefaultLINE()
print(len(lineModDetector.getModalities()))

mask = cv2.bitwise_not(template)[:,:,1]

ret, boundingBox = lineModDetector.addTemplate([template], "circle", mask)
print(ret)
print(boundingBox)

target = cv2.imread('../image/materias/light.jpg',)
target = cv2.resize( target, (200, 200))

results = lineModDetector.match(target, threshold=80)
```

I got the following error when running this code:

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) sources.size() == modalities.size() in function 'cv::linemod::Detector::match'
```

I try to implement `linemod` using python

Answer (score 0):

according to doc: https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d7/d07/classcv_1_1linemod_1_1Detector.html
sources Source images, one for each modality.

you should use it like this:

target = cv2.imread('../image/materias/light.jpg',)

target = cv2.resize( target, (200, 200))

target = (target,)

results = lineModDetector.match(target, threshold=80)